# Converting from string to Integer throws exception. Visual Studio '15

Tags: visual-studio-2015

So the problem here is, when I press the "OK" button which starts to run the calculations, it throws and exception for intHour = Convert.ToDecimal(txtbHoursReq.Text) I have tried to change it to, Toint16 and Toint32 but it still throws the exception. I do not know what I am doing wrong. I have googled it, read through my book looking at the examples and still can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
Sub calculateCost()
    '   This function calculates the cost to rent a yacht depending on size and hours
    Dim sessionPrice As Integer
    Dim intHour As Integer
    Dim intYachtLength As Integer

    '   This functiin determines the price depending on length
    intYachtLength = lboxLength.SelectedIndex()
    Select Case intYachtLength
        Case 0
            intYachtLength = 95.0
        Case 1
            intYachtLength = 137.0
        Case 2
            intYachtLength = 160.0
        Case 3
            intYachtLength = 192.0
        Case 4
            intYachtLength = 250.0
        Case 5
            intYachtLength = 400.0
        Case 6
            intYachtLength = 550.0
    End Select

    '   Converts txtbHoursReq into an integer, then calculates the price of rental based on size of yacht and time of rental
    lblCostLength.Text = intYachtLength
    intHour = Convert.ToDecimal(txtbHoursReq.Text)' Throws an exception
    sessionPrice = intYachtLength * intHour
    lblDisplayPrice.Text = sessionPrice



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you put a break point and see what is actually being passed in txtbHoursReq.Text? I did a prototype and can't see why it will throw an exception if the value in the text box is a representation of a number: Here are the only possible exceptions, which one did you get?

```
public void ConvertStringDecimal(string stringVal)
    {
        decimal decimalVal = 0;

        try
        {
            decimalVal = System.Convert.ToDecimal(stringVal);
            Response.Write(decimalVal);
        }
        catch (System.OverflowException)
        {
            Response.Write("System.OverflowException.");
        }
        catch (System.FormatException)
        {
            Response.Write("System.FormatException");
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentNullException)
        {
            Response.Write("System.ArgumentNullException");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am getting a FormatException was unhandled. 'System.FormatException" orccurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: That means whatever is coming through that textbox is not the string representation of a decimal. That string must be made of digits and/or decimal point only.

Comment: Correct, I forgot to mention, I am testing to make sure that my MsgBox comes up when no data is entered in the textboxs. So when I press the "OK" button with no data in the forum it throws this exception. When there is data though it works just fine. I am sorry I forgot to say this.

Comment: So I didn't figure out the exact problem, but look at code I have written before, I just swapped it into intHour = Val(strNumHours) which did the trick thankfully, now it does not throw and exception. Thank you for the help.